# fgets puts the newline character in the end of the buffer

Tags: c, fgets

I run this code: (On Ubuntu 16.04 with VMware)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ARRAY_SIZE 50


int main()
{
    char str[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int i;

    FILE* fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("File hasn't opened.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while(fgets(str, ARRAY_SIZE, fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf("str length is %d\n", strlen(str));
        for(i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
            printf("index is %d, char is %d\n", i, str[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

`test.txt` has only 1 character in it (the character '1'), no newline character after the only character.

Why `strlen(str)` returns 2 and not 1?

And why the second character is a newline character if there's no newline character in test.txt?

Comment: "*if there's no newline character in test.txt?*" Are you really sure there isn't? What is the file's size in bytes?

Comment: @alk the size is 2 bytes

Comment: @AlbertLeibnitz: That's because there's a newline on the end. I ran your code and verified manually. No newline on the end, no newline from `fgets`.

Comment: If the file size is 2 bytes then there is no more question.

Comment: @AlbertLeibnitz: So, what would the 2nd byte  most likely be then? ;)

Comment: The file might have only one *visible* character, but if the size is two then there must be a second character hiding in it. What is the output you get from your program? More specifically, what is the output of the inner loop where you print out the contents of the array `str`? Please [edit] your question to show the output.

Comment: @alk I didn't put the newline character there. Maybe it's the app I use (gedit)? The `test.txt` file includes only '1' character in it. It has only 1 line in it, so how there's a newline character if there's only 1 line and 1 character in that only line?

Comment: Especially under Linux, many texteditors will end a file with a new-line character, because that's the "proper" way text files should look. Perhaps gedit has a setting for that? (But I think your program should assume that there can be a new-line character at the end of input you get from `fgets` and act accordingly.)

Comment: What is your platform? If it's linux/macos try `od -x test.txt`  in a shell and tell us what the output is. I'm sure it's something like `30 0A`

Comment: A text file that does _not_ have a newline at the end is considered "malformed" by most editors [under posix systems]. For example if you _did_ have a file that had _no_ newline at the end, if you do: `vi file` and then `:w`, and `:q`, then `vi` will "correct" the file

Comment: @Jabberwocky 1)`0000000 0a31` 2)`0000002`

Comment: @AlbertLeibnitz so there _is_ a newline in the file. The `0a` is the newline, and the `31` is the `'1'`. That's exactly what everybody has been telling you during the last 20 minutes.

Comment: you can also verify with `wc -c test.txt` and see how many bytes its printing.

Comment: Try `oc -c test.txt` to see the contents of the file

Comment: If your file has 1 line in it, that would indicate that it contains a newline.  If it does not have a newline, then the file would have 0 lines.

Comment: @WilliamPursell not really, if a textfile contains just the 3 letters `ABC` it contains 1 line that you can read with `fgets` without problems. If it contains the 3 letters `ABC` followed by a newline ( `ABC\n`) it contains 2 lines, the second line being empty. At least that's what all my text editors tell me.

Comment: @Jabberwocky You've got it wrong. ABC\n is exactly one line. An editor telling you otherwise has an off-by-one error or worse. A file with ABC does not contain anything looking like a line as defined by POSIX, because POSIX lines *must* end with a newline. C implementations are free to handle non-POSIXly formed input as they see fit.

Comment: @Jens OK if we're talking about POSIX the definition it maybe different, but in real world there are many text files around that don't have a `\n` at the end of the last line, and I never had the slightest problems with them. All text editors I use have no problem with dealing with such files either, and I've never seen an `fgets` implementation that can't handle text files that don't end with a `\n`

Comment: If we allow `wc` to be the arbiter of the count, then indeed a file with no newline has zero lines.  `printf abc | wc -l`

Comment: OT: regarding: `printf("str length is %d\n", strlen(str));`  The function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`. not a `int`.